# Bootstrap glyphicon link not underlined

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, hide

I have the following code: But how can I hide the underlined glyphicon?

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" action="#{languageGeneralListController.doEditLanguageGeneral(languageGeneral)}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Editieren"></span>
</p:commandLink>
```

Here my CSS:

```
a:link {
    color: #1BA1E2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #1BA1E2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1BA1E2;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #1BA1E2;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover img {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried with the last a:hover img but it doesn't work.
Could anybody help me, please.

Comment: Instead of a:hover img have you tried a:hover span? Only because you have a span instead of a true img

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
a:hover .glyphicon {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As aDroidman pointed out your css is targeting an image.

**Edit**

Have a look at this example and see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/xae8n/

For a link with a glyphicon in it you will need to these two things:

1. Assign a class to the link, then use that class to disable the normal link underline.
2. Assign a class to the text inside the link that use that to underline the text when the class from (1) is hovered over.

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Can you post a working example so I can have a look?

Comment: A example is in my first post.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, let me know how it goes for you.